# wrong fonts embedded in pdf when using 'text.usetex' = true

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to render my plots with setting the rcParameter 'text.usetex = True' and save it to a pdf.

If i set 'text.usetex = False' and set the font to 'Times New Roman' --> only TimesNewRomanPS-ItalicMT and TimesNewRomanPSMT are embedded (see [usetex_false](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65CvQ.png)).

But if i set 'text.usetex = True' --> instead of Times only cm-fonts (eg CMMI12, CMR10,...) are embedded (see [usetex_true)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epaSF.png).

How to can I use 'text.usetex = True' and embed Times New Roman fonts instead of cm-fonts?

My Code:

```
"""
Demo of a line plot on a polar axis.
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

with plt.rc_context({'text.usetex' : False, #---> no Times New Roman embedded when set to true, instead cm-fonts
                     'font.family' : 'serif',
                     'font.serif': 'Times New Roman',
                     'mathtext.fontset' : 'custom',
                     'mathtext.cal' : 'serif:cursive',
                     'mathtext.rm'  : 'serif',
                     'mathtext.tt'  : 'monospace',
                     'mathtext.it'  : 'serif:italic',
                     'mathtext.bf'  : 'serif:bold',
                     'mathtext.sf'  : 'sans'}):
    r = np.arange(0, 3.0, 0.01)
    theta = 2 * np.pi * r
    r = r*1000000000
    ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
    ax.plot(theta, r, color='b', linewidth=3)

    ax.grid(True)

    plt.title(r'Some text with latex in it  $10_4  \times \theta = \Phi$')
    plt.savefig(r'Test_text_embedded_of.pdf', papertype='None')
```

Comment: I am unable to reproduce your problem. I get the same font independent of usetex.  `ax.title.get_font_properties()` and `ax.title.get_fontname()` are also identical.

Comment: `ax.title.get_font_properties()` and `ax.title.get_fontname()` are indentical for me too. Maybe something with the backend?

Answer (score 0):

For me adding following lines helped:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf import FigureCanvasPgf
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.backend_bases.register_backend('pdf', FigureCanvasPgf)
```